# Agglutination in Proto-Indo-European

Tags: morphology, proto-indo-european, reference-request, grammar, agglutination

Based on numerous sources, it seems clear that Proto-Indo-European was

1. Productively agglutinative with non-root morphemes (and perhaps some specific roots that are also able to act like bound morphemes), and
2. Derivationally agglutinative with roots in deriving new words.

What I haven't been able to find a clear answer on is whether PIE was productively agglutinative with roots, as is found in many modern Germanic languages (i.e. German). Is this still an unanswered question?

Comment: It's hard to see what kind of evidence could answer this question, as that kind of compounding verges on being syntactic and we can't reconstruct much syntax. I suppose if we could reconstruct some words that were then analysable into compounds of known roots, that would be evidence for the process, but I can't see what could be evidence against.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps one possible indirect line of evidence would be how broad the genitive case is in Proto-Indo-European. The productive use of compounding or agglutination frees up potential functions of the genitive such that the genitive can have a very narrow range of meanings (e.g. it's almost synonymous with possession in English and German). Alternately, if a language lacks such mechanisms the genitive case is likely to be more broad, e.g. in Latin.

Comment: Is the reason you mention German that you do not find English productively agglutinative with roots? Apart from the fact that English doesn't always write compound nouns as one orthographic word, I'm not convinced that English is less productive in this respect than German.

Comment: That's a good point, @dainichi, and something I've thought about before. English does use what I call analytic agglutination (perhaps there's a more proper term for it) extensively (one of my favorite examples of extremes of this is a BBC headline: Gaza White Flag Deaths Probe Call). But yes, I used German as an example because I'm thinking in English the words remain morphologically distinct.

Comment: German has productive noun compounding but is not generally described as an agglutinating language. It doesn't really go for verb compounding though. Japanese and Chinese have both noun compounding and verb compounding for contrast...

Comment: "agglutinative with roots" - usually that is not named "agglutination", because main term for that is "compound", and they are mostly agglutinative in all languages, "agglutination" is usually used only about grammatic morphemes like case ending morphemes and verb ending morphemes, and they are fusional in many languages, and fusional in many languages.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it was very much. The roots would be either just concatenated, or the thematic vowel -o- or the glue suffix -i- would be used.

Examples include:

- ***a̯entio̯q̆os*** "face" (thing in front of eyes)
- ***a̯rĝipta̯i̯os*** swift-winged
- ***cleumntom*** good reputation
- ***demspotis*** head of family
- ***u̯icpotis*** settlement elder
- ***dmpedos*** house floor
- ***du̯eiplos*** double
- ***dusdius*** bad weather (literally, bad sky)
- ***ğeo̯uq̆olos*** cowherd
- ***q̆tu̯rpedos*** tetrapod
- ***sma̯ecsia̯*** carriot (having one axis)
- ***somoĝne̯i̯os*** blood relative

One also should note that the most of PIE personal names were compounds of two roots, similar to Greek Cleopatra, Alexander, Theophilos, Patrocleus or Slavic Yaroslav, Vladimir, Yaropolk.

Comment: Was this type of agglutination productive, or primarily in derivation?

Comment: Both Greek and Sanskrit demonstrate such features, even in verbs, but is it true/full agglutination? As far as I know, only Lydian has true agglutinative qualities and that could be because it came in close contact with agglutinative languages e.g. Hattic.

Comment: I would not call this agglutination. I would call it compounding: compounds of more than two elements are rare to non-existent.

Comment: @Midas: If you're referring to Annalic Hittite syntax (NU-pron-pron-pron NP NP NP ..), that's clearly an artificial style, not agglutination. Adn I agree with Colin that PIE compounds were clearly possible, and that this is not evidence of agglutination. PIE inflectional morphology is very clearly fusional, with multi-dimensional paradigms; agglutinative languages tend to have one-dimensional paradigms.

Comment: @jlawler: No, I was not referring to Hittite. I was referring strictly to Lydian.

Comment: this is funny because my browser shows whitespace instead of the diacrits, so it looks like sperate words, but probably not the separation you had in mind. e.g. ğeo uc olos, q tu rpodos, sma ecsia, somoĝne i os. (still makes sense: earth animal master -- maybe; what do rapid -- no, but yes; one axis -- as intended (reflexes are ...?); like many of us -- haha, no, glue-infix also no, but yes, that looks like agglutination of sorts

Comment: @vectory upgrade your browser. ğeo̯uq̆olos has nothing to do with earth, the root ğeo̯u- meant "cow" (and its direct cognate). q̆tu̯rpedos comes from q̆tu̯r "four-" and ped- "foot"

Comment: @Midas Is there strong evidence for Lydian being agglutinative? Melchert argues that it's probably not, but it's difficult to say anything for certain given how little data survives.

Comment: @Draconis: It is debatable at least to say. As you said, we have too little data.